# Custom switch does not show On/Off Image in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-and-use-a-custom-switch-control-in-xamarin-forms/

"OnImage" and "OffImage" does not work when i make a custom renderer following the guide above. I see no image when i click on or off.

In my class, I send in a HTTP url and then convert that URL to a UIImage. It works successfully as i've added breakpoints all the way. I even tried with a image in my library to see if that would change the outcome but it didnt.

```
public class Switch_iOS : SwitchRenderer
{
    Version version = new Version(ObjCRuntime.Constants.Version);
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Switch> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.OldElement != null || e.NewElement == null)
            return;
        var view = (CustomSwitch)Element;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(view.SwitchThumbImage))
        {
            if (version > new Version(6, 0))
            {   
                Control.OnImage = FromUrl(view.SwitchThumbImage);

                Control.OffImage = FromUrl(view.SwitchThumbImage);
            }
            else
            {
                Control.ThumbTintColor = view.SwitchThumbColor.ToUIColor();
            }
        }
    }

    public UIImage FromUrl(string uri)
    {
        using (var url = new NSUrl(uri))
        using (var data = NSData.FromUrl(url))
            return UIImage.LoadFromData(data);
    }
}
```

Is "Control.OnImage" and "Control.OffImage" not working with the latest Xamarin Forms? I also intend to make a background image to the switch.

Comment: "seems to not work" is not a helpful description of the problem.  Are you saying that neither image displays?  Or that only one does?  Or something else?

Comment: Does not work.. I will rephrase the quesiton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unfortunately** , about `OnImage` and `OffImage` of **UISwitch** , *from iOS 7 has no effect.*

Have a look at [the apple document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswitch/1623689-onimage?language=objc) :

> In iOS 7 and later, this property has no effect.
>
> In iOS 6, this image represents the interior contents of the switch.
>   The image you specify is composited with the switch’s rounded bezel
>   and thumb to create the final appearance.

Instead you can use

- `onTintColor` to set the tint color of the switch when it is turned on.
- `tintColor` to set the tint color of the switch when it is turned off.
- `thumbTintColor` to set the tint color of the thumb.

Comment: ouch ok, so no possibility to add an image? :( u know of any workaorund in xamarin forms? trying to make this: https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/image.gif

Comment: @DiddanDo Yeah . As far as I know, unless a view is customized to implement all the functions of `UISwitch`, the image cannot be added on `UISwitch`.

Comment: okok. u know of any github repo that has done a custom one in xamarin?

Comment: @DiddanDo The  `Syncfusion.Xamarin.Core` nuget packages can achieve that by using `SfSwitch` . Refer to [here](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/switch/customization#images)

Comment: yea thats just what i need. but synfusion is so expensive

Comment: @DiddanDo Okey , about other good github repos , haven't found . If anything, I will update here later :-)